# Showing text upon a click

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

I am attending an entry level HTML/CSS/JS course and our first assignment is to make a simple website about ourselves. We need to have a horizontal menu that when clicked displays certain information. For example, clicking "description" should display a short paragraph describing ourselves. From what I've researched it seems that my answer lies with using JQuery but I don't believe he expects us to know that nor utilize it this early. Is there another option that I may not be seeing?

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Jeremy Ortiz</title>
<div id="header">
<h1>A Little About Jeremy Ortiz</h1>
</div>

</head>

<body>
    <img src="hwpic.jpg" alt="Me">

    <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
     <h2>Navigation</h2>
     <ul>
      <li><a class="selected" href="">Description</a></li>
      <li><a href="">A form</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Course List</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Information</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



#header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #6CF;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    bottom: 148px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#content {
    padding: 10px;
}

#nav {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Just make a html document for each page and have your links redirect to each relevant page. (`description.html`, `contactInfo.html`, ect) No javascript or jquery needed.

Comment: Post your CSS too

Comment: If your assignment included using SO to find your answer, please note you are supposed to ***search*** first and only ***ask*** if your question was not already asked/answered before. Now, without even searching and taking a wild guess. what do you think? Has your question been asked before?

Comment: I guess I may not have looked hard enough but upon my initial search a lot of answers pointed to JQuery solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will assume your goal is to accomplish this task using basic Javascript instead of changing pages by navigating the user using the `<a>` elements. I understand that there are more efficient methods of performing this but I chose to present the information in a hopefully simple easily readable manner.

The way I would accomplish this is by changing your `<a>` elements:

```
<a class="selected" href="">Description</a>
```

To button elements and add the 'onclick' property with the function to call when the button is clicked:

```
<button onclick="displayDescription()">Click Me</button>
```

Now we need to create the elements that will be displayed upon clicking the button. For this we create some `<div>` other container that we can hide until the corresponding button is clicked.

```
<div id="description" style="display: none;">
  Displayed when the description button is clicked.
</div>
```

Note**  For every button we will need to create a `<div style="display: none;">` to hide the information until its corresponding button is clicked.

Now we can create our Javascript function:

```
function displayDescription() {
    var x = document.getElementById('description');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Note once again that in this method each Javascript function will map to a button in the same way each hidden  will map to the same button.

If you need more help I recommend checking out w3schools and specifically for this problem here is a link to what you need to accomplish with your assignment.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

I hope this was helpful as I just wrote this during one of my college classes I will probably formalize my answer more at a later time today.